# Databases interconnection

Tags: mongodb, binding, relational

I have to interconnect different databases, beetwen a relational database (postgresql) and a nosql database (mongodb).

There are some semistructured entities, then, I put them in mongoDB, and I have some relational schema that, logically, is stored it into postgres.

**The problem:** I need to bind some conections beetwenn these entities/documents/whatever.

**Schema** :

- Postgres entity[id,name,....]
- MongoDB document[objectid,name,....]

**Solutions:**

***1*** - Put ids as 'foreign keys':

- Postgres entity[id,name,**mongo_objectId**....]
- MongoDB document[objectid,name,**postgres_entityId**....]

  I don't like these solution because:
- This is not friendly
- ids can change, I mean, if I would migrate my postgres to another kind of schema.

***2*** - Generate friendly string keys to bind the schemas:

- Postgres entity[id,name,**key**....]
- MongoDB document[objectid,name,**key**....]

Keys would be strings, uniques and friendly, I mean if the name is "Michàél Knïght", the key would be "michael-knight" or "michael-knight_{counter}" if it already exists in database.

**My question** :

Could it cause performance problems? I think integer values are better for indexing ...

Answer (score 0):

There are internal optimizations around ObjectId in MongoDB and it is more compact that the equivalent string. Primary keys are generally immutable so I don't think Solution 1 is a bad idea.